# insert the content of a text file into a variable

Tags: matlab

I want to load a text file whit ASCII characters and put all the content into a varialbe in MATLAB, This is the code i tried :

```
f =fopen('tp.txt')
```

The result I get is 1, then it increments each time I excute this code line.

However, when I try :

```
f =load('tp.txt')
```

I get this error :

```
??? Error using ==> load
Number of columns on line 1 of ASCII file D:\Cours\TP\tp.txt
must be the same as previous lines.

Error in ==> TPTI at 3
f =load('tp.txt')
```

My goal is to count the occurance of each charachter then calculate the propabilites and the entropies.

Any idea?

Comment: Does the ASCII file contain one line or several lines? Do you want to put those contents into a variable as a string? As an array of strings?

Comment: The file contains several lines. I want to put the contents into a string variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
%// Import file contents as a string
str = importdata('tp.txt'); %// each line is a cell
str = [str{:}]; %// concat all lines into a single string

%// Remove spaces. Maybe you want to remove other characters as well: punctuation...
str = regexprep(str, '\s', '');

%// Count frequency of each character:
freq = histc(double(str), 0:255); %// convert characters to ASCII codes and count
```